# Create envelope with template id and values for custom and standard fields should be filled before sending to recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I have recorded below video to explain what I am trying to achieve.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/23765847?key=c6107a99bee1285ea91f533a1e52b1f6

Please help me if someone knows how to do it with API V2.1

I did tried with below request but its not working as expected.

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "b2f0***************************c1af"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "name": "Test USer",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Seller",
                "tabs": {
                  "dateTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "date signed",
                      "value": "01-01-2024"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with below request but its not working.

````
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "11111",
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "name": "Shravi",
                "roleName": "Seller",
                "recipientId": "111111",
                "tabs": {
                  "companyTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabId": "f846a227*************************bebfb3",
                      "value": "AAAAAAAAAA"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "templateId": "b2f0d********************ec1efc1af",
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}```
````

Comment: Welcome! Please ***check*** (accept) the best answer to your question. ***Thank you!***

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You need to use the tab attribute `tabId`, not `tabLabel`.

In the DocuSign webapp, this is the "Data label" attribute for the tab.

This [live example](https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/QWBGwve?editors=0010) gives an example. See line 113 of the Javascript.

### Added

The value of `companyTabs` can't be set. See the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/)

Try with a text tab.

### StackOverflow is not a bulletin board

If you have any more questions, open a ***new*** question on StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not for back and forth discussions.

Comment: Please check my post I have added additional request details but its not working.

Comment: When I tried same request its not working for me. I tried with texttabs, listtabs, radiotabs, none of them are working. Is there any setting at developer account level which I needs to enable?

Answer (score 0):

This is your request

```json
{
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "1",
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "d76bda09-fb05-4c58-a5fe-7273151b1a95"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "customFields": {
                        "listCustomFields": [
                            {
                                "name": "Envelope list custom field 1",
                                "show": "true",
                                "value": "value 5"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "test@test.com",
                                "name": "Rupa",
                                "clientUserId": 1000,
                                "roleName": "Signer1",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "customFields": [
                                    "field1: value 1",
                                    "field2: value 2"
                                ],
                                "tabs": {
                                    "radioGroupTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "groupName": "Indian",
                                            "radios": [
                                                {
                                                    "selected": "true",
                                                    "tabId": "6e0248fe-df91-449f-8853-948764fb0deb",
                                                    "value": "Yes"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my request

```json
{
    "emailBlurb": "Create an envelope with a templateId",
    "emailSubject": "Template",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "a975e665-f0c1-4469-a3af-3268f3fb0d19"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "test@test.com",
                                "name": "Test user",
                                "recipientId": "76987934",
                                "roleName": "Tester",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "radioGroupTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "groupName": "Indian",
                                            "radios": [
                                                {
                                                    "selected": "true",
                                                    "tabId": "6e0248fe-df91-449f-8853-948764fb0deb",
                                                    "value": "Yes"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

This one is not working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this working. It was a config issue. Not a code issue  I didn't realize that recipient roles could have blank Name and Email in the Template configs in the actual website. Then in code, just referencing the role name, and then putting in an email address and name.